# Docker snap auto update breaking containers

Tags: docker

I installed docker as a snap on my machine. I also have other applications installed with snap. I like that these other applications auto-update.

The issue comes when the docker snap updates, it breaks my container networks. I run an ELK stack on my machine (elastic search, logstash, kibana), and every time I have to do `docker-compose down` then `docker-compose up -d` to bring it back to a working condition.

From what I can see, the containers are still online. I can still access them through the ports I set, but they can't talk to each other. Kibana will just spit out a "Kibana is not ready" page when I try to access it.

[Here is a picture of what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22mdb.png)

I have **3 paths** on how to fix this:

1. **Migrate away from snap for docker.** The only issue is that I found no resources online to do this when I looked. This to me seems like the best options. I'm not sure how migrating volumes would work.
2. **Disable snap for only docker.** The issue with this is you can only snap completely off or on. There is no way to disable it for a single snap. From what I googled this was by design
3. **docker-compose option?** Maybe I missed something in my docker-compose file? I set all my containers to `restart: always` so it would boot when my machine comes online.

I am running on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

You can add a software source to get up-to-date Docker installed as a regular package.See instructions [here](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/). The package is called `docker-ce` not `docker`.